# Ask a JDBC driver which version of JDBC it supports

Tags: java, jdbc, version, driver

Is there a place in the [JDBC API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/package-summary.html) to interrogate a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) as to the version of [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) it supports?

I found [`Driver::jdbcCompliant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#jdbcCompliant()), but that is simply boolean, with no indication of with which *version* the driver is compliant.

I found [`Driver::getMajorVersion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#getMajorVersion()) & `getMinorVersion`. But I presume that is for the version number of that particular driver implementation project, not the version of JDBC the driver supports.

➥ Is there a standard way to ask the driver the version of JDBC it targets?

Comment: I think the version of JDBC is whatever your language compatibility version is... or are you planning to use a non-standard driver or 3rd party implementation of `java.sql`?

Comment: @JimGarrison My question is about the *driver* implementation, not the JDBC API bundled with Java. Every JDBC driver author targets a particular version of the JDBC API. Successive versions of the JDBC spec add features. Older drivers are forward-compatible with later versions of Java. But those older drivers will not magically support the newer features found in later versions of the JDBC spec. So there are cases where it might be convenient to ask the driver its implemented version of the JDBC spec.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to check for support for various features independently anyway, because a driver supporting any JDBC 4.3 features doesn't necessarily imply it supporting all JDBC 4.2 features.

Comment: I found a solution, and [posted on that older Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57767011/642706) preceding mine: [`DatabaseMetaData::getJDBCMajorVersion`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getJDBCMajorVersion()) & `getJDBCMinorVersion`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer indeed, for example Spring framework tests driver features and disables them dynamically (although it might use the driver declared JDBC version for some baseline).